# ?listPreferredItemHeight causing inflating exception

Tags: android

I have a commom module being referenced by many modules with a dimens.xml file with following:

```
<dimen name="margin_botton">?listPreferredItemHeight</dimen>
```

Then in this same commom module I have a generic layout (generic_recycler_list) that uses:

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_bottom"
```

Now modules where I use this layout I'm getting "error inflating class androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView".

I'm not finding any correlation why this could happen, as soon as I remove android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_bottom" from the layout all works. Would you have any hints what could cause such an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is easy, you cannot use such reference in dimens.xml, it would be practical and despite the editor never complies when doing so you get at the end the mentioned exception.